# Binding evaluation mechanics

Tags: wpf, binding

Given:

```
<TextBox Text='{Binding MyCollection[MyIndex].MyProperty}'/>
```

where:

- `MyCollection` is an observable collection of `MyClass` items
- `MyClass` implements `MyProperty` (a `string` actually)
- `MyClass` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`

then, next time the binding is re-evaluated, where exactly will `TextBox.Text` get the value from? I can think of two possible sources:

- **either** `MyClass` instance actually contained in MyCollection (i.e. actually *call the collection indexer to obtain the updated value*),
- **or** the instance present in the collection *at the moment when binding set-up occurs*, even when it's already absent in the collection?

If it turns out to be the former case, can I somehow approach the latter behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding, when it's re-evaluated, will use the entire binding syntax, including calling the indexer.

Comment: Supposed so. However, I can't catch the indexer call with a breakpoint when the change occurs, that's why I asked... Will have to look somewhere else :)

Comment: @vines Sometimes getting the binding to actually update is tricky - raising PropertyChanged with string.Empty should force a full re-evaluation of all bindings in the View, which should let you see this in action.